# Blender shuts down in Texture Paint mode

Tags: uv, texture-painting

My Blender keeps crashing after I have been in texture paint mode for a random amount of time. I have tried painting for 30 minutes sometimes 3 hours. 
Then it suddenly shuts down without warning or error codes.

What could possibly be happening?

I am 100% positive, that this isn't caused by me hitting a random exit key. It only happens when I am doing some texture painting.

Comment: What size of image are you using to paint on as a texture, and how much system ram do you have? What version of Blender are you using and what are your system specs?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how you unwrapped the model?